# Vehicle Booking System

Tags: powerapps

Apologies if this has been asked before, however I am transitioning over from Access and am getting slightly lost with how power-apps functions.

I am creating a vehicle tracking app which is using 2 sharepoint lists. The home screen has a gallery list of all the vehicles within the fleet, taken from the list "VehicleRegister". Upon selecting the required vehicle the app navigates to a booking page with an edit form which accesses a list named "BookingLog", this contains the fields;

Vehicle Registration < Relating to the VehicleRegister List
Booked out by
Date booked...
etc

Currently I use OnSelect,

NewForm(VehicleBookingForm);Navigate(BookingDetails, ScreenTransition.Fade)

To access the form where the user will input their information and date to book the vehicle etc. However how can I get it so that when the user is brought to this edit form the combobox with the selected vehicle is already selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass 3rd parameter to the Navigation method

```
NewForm(VehicleBookingForm);Navigate(BookingDetails, ScreenTransition.Fade,{variablename:Dropdown.SelectedText.Value})
```

In the form where you want to show default selected combo box, follow below steps:

- select combo box
- go to DefaultSelectedItems property
- write below code 
  `Lookup(Choices(datasourcename.'fieldname'),Value = variablename)`

Please change *variablename* to the variable which you want to use, change *datasourcename* to your data source name, *dropdown* to your dropdown name and *fieldname* to your field name

I hope this helps